# How do I vertically scale an image while keeping the image bottom at a fixed position?

Tags: css

How can I have an image scale vertically while fixing the location of the bottom of the image? Currently, the image stretches in both directions (up / down). I have also tried translating the position of the image but this removed the scaling effect.

Here is my keyframe definition:

```
@-webkit-keyframes readyToFight {
   0% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.0); }
   100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1.07); }
}
```

... and here is how I am using the keyframe:

```
-webkit-animation: readyToFight 0.5s linear 0.5s infinite alternate;
```

Comment: How about [`transform-origin: bottom center;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)?

Comment: post a live fiddle please..